# Show sizes of all subfolders in ordered fashion (Power Shell)

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I found this code... which is supposed to take sizes of all level 1 subfolders in a directory. And order them from largest to smallest in GUI. It runs in power shell. Previous least complicated version worked, but it doesn't reorder subfolders by size. Ordered ascending, or descending would be fine in both cases.

Source: http://woshub.com/powershell-get-folder-sizes/#comment-5195

**What i tried:** i tried other location than "C:". I don't understand this code, so i have no idea why it doesn't work... PS just hangs at >> and nothing is happening... I ran PS as admin! Ordering folders in windows explorer doesn't work btw and i don't like installing many programs!

```
$targetfolder='C:\'
$dataColl = @()
gci -force $targetfolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_ -is [io.directoryinfo] } | % {
$len = 0
gci -recurse -force $_.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length }
$foldername = $_.fullname
$foldersize= '{0:N2}' -f ($len / 1Gb)
$dataObject = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “foldername” -value $foldername
Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name “foldersizeGb” -value $foldersize
$dataColl += $dataObject
}
$dataColl | Out-GridView -Title “Size of subdirectories”
```

Comment: As for this... [I don't understand this code] ... then why are you running it? Never run code you do not understand, no matter where or who you get it from, especially destructive code (create, update/modify, delete stuff). Before you use anyone code in a live environment, you should test it in a lab or [a virtual standalone machine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview). Why are you not contacting the author to fix this if the previous version worked? The code you posted has syntax issues. Those quotes are the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment.

Copying and pasting from some website, is not prudent, as it can and will have a bunch of random characters, and punctuation that is not valid in real code. Thus, will not run at all, or if it does it will fail.

For example, those fancy quotes, need to be changed to simple quotes. Simple strings should be a single quote, and variable expansion (and some string formatting needs require double quotes). Cmdlet property names don't really need quotes at all, except if they have a space in them.

This also means you are very new to PowerShell (that's fine) and thus, should really spend the time getting up to speed on it. Youtube (just search for beginning Powershell, intermediate PowerShell, Advanced PowerShell, PowerShell file and folder management, etc.) is your friend, and there is no reason to run this code as an Admin. In most cases for daily use, you should never need to run PowerShell as admin. Only use it when it is a requirement.

Most of this code is basic PowerShell stuff. Yet, it is using a lot of aliases/shorthand code. This is why aliases should not be in scripts. Also, doing this on your C drive will take a very, very, long time, depending on how big and how much data is on your drive.

They are great for interactive/throw-away code, but not scripts, functions, modules, cmdlets, shared code, etc., otherwise, they are just should be avoided. Why, because many have never seen, used to even know what they are, and they are not guaranteed to work in all environments and operating systems, depending on how the environment is configured.

Change all those aliases to their true verbose names. You can use the Get-Alias cmdlet to see all available and then fix that up, or use Get-Alias on each of them one at a time.

```
Get-Alias 'gci', '?', '%'
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                 Version Source
----------- ----                 ------- ------
Alias       gci -> Get-ChildItem               
Alias       % -> ForEach-Object                
Alias       ? -> Where-Object                  
Alias       h -> Get-History                   
Alias       r -> Invoke-History                
Alias       % -> ForEach-Object  
#>
```

See the help files for any cmdlet details and examples.

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Help -Online
```

So, this to get you started. PowerShell is a verbose language for a reason. Easy to read, understand, and troubleshoot, as well as self-documenting. As far as sorting, PowerShell has the Sort-Object cmdlet for that (again see the help files for details). In the Out-GridView, just as you would in Excel, just click the column header to sort ascending or Descending.

```
# Set the target folder
$targetfolder = 'C:\'

# Initialize the array
$dataColl = @()

# Get all the files in the $targetfolder, where the type is a directory
Get-ChildItem -Force -Path $targetfolder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object { $PSItem -is [io.directoryinfo] } | 
ForEach {
    # For each directory, collect and calculate the total length/size.
    $len = 0
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $PSItem.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    ForEach { $len += $PSItem.length }

    $foldername = $PSItem.fullname
    
    # Convert length/size to gigabytes format
    $foldersize = '{0:N2}' -f ($len / 1Gb)

    # Create a new custom object for output
    $dataObject = New-Object PSObject

    # Add a now note property hole and output this info
    Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name foldername -value $foldername
    Add-Member -inputObject $dataObject -memberType NoteProperty -name foldersizeGb -value $foldersize

    # add to the collection
    $dataColl += $dataObject
}
# Send the collected data to the OutGridView cmdlet
$dataColl | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Size of subdirectories'
```

As for this [io.directoryinfo], this is really not needed, and Get-ChildItem has a -File (for only file type) and -Directory (for only directory type). The [io.directoryinfo] is a .Net namespace for the same thing, and really a legacy PowerShell thing. There are reasons use .Net namespaces, but this is not one of them unless you ar eon legacy PowerShell. Meaning v3 and earlier.

Always use the full verbose names in your code that goes into production, or you share. If it is just interactive stuff or just for you, use whatever supported shorthand/alias you choose.

Comment: There is an extra simple quote `'` in your last line of your code !  Replace `Out-GridView -Title 'Size of subdirectories''`  by this `Out-GridView -Title 'Size of subdirectories'`

Comment: yeppers corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong wtih that code, but it uses some out-dated constructs & unnecessary intermediate variables. Here's a simplified version that works.

To learn something, follow postanote's advice about *aliases* & `Get-Help`.

The code does recursively query every file in the folder & it's subfolders for size, so test on a more limited folder structure first -- `c:\` may have over-whelmed it. Be aware that the Gb conversion & formatting will list smaller folders as `0.00` in size. I changed to `1Kb` for testing.

```
$targetfolder = 'C:\'
gci $targetfolder -Directory -force -ea SilentlyContinue | % {
    $len = 0
    gci $_.fullname -File -recurse -force -ea SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FolderName   =  $_.fullname
        FolderSizeGb = '{0:N2}' -f ($len / 1Gb)
    }
} | Out-GridView -Title “Size of subdirectories”
```